# Is it possible to make model class as a role in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, authorization, cancan

I know that there are many excellent authorization gems out there like cancan, declarative authorization, cantango etc etc. I want to know is it possible to use the model class as a role itself?

Like for e.g. let there be two resources tutor and student then is it possible to make tutor and student as roles also? I am asking this because I have different authentication pages for different resources as my resources are totally different from each other and I am not going for a single user class for authentication.

Also guide me if I am doing it totally wrong as I am new to rails :-).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "yes".  For cancan, ultimately you are defining what constitutes authorized access and you can do that however you want.  Most of the automatic pieces do assume a user model but there's no hard requirement to use the helpers provided.  You'd define the authorization logic in the ability.rb file as usual but manually call `authorize!` in your controller.

That said, why not make life simpler and go with a single user model, but make the user's role be context-dependent?  Then you benefit from an established workflow for auth and probably have a clearer domain model as well.

Comment: There's a perfect solution for the single User model with different levels of authorization. You can simply add a bitmask integer field representing the different users authorization levels (which individually can be stored as constants). An example would be 1 for admin, 2 for manager, 3 for admin and manager, 4 for employee, etc. The [role_model](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model) gem offers this functionality right out of the box and compliments cancan perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Dave and Cyle for clarifying my doubts.